# Is there a way, to add a dynamic function "hint" to an abstract base class, without actually add a function?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.8

I am working on a project, where a set of event functions are tested in a tree of objects.

```
class ObjectA:
    pass

class ObjectB:
    def on_event(text: str):
        print(text)

many_objects = [
    ObjectA(),
    ObjectA(),
    ObjectA(),
    ObjectA(),
    ObjectA(),
    ObjectB(),  # <<<
    ObjectA()
]

def call_on_event(text: str):
    for obj in many_objects:
        if hasattr(obj, 'on_event'):
            func = getattr(obj, 'on_event')
            if callable(func):
                func.on_event(text)
```

Now, there are many different events (>50), which are dynamically tested on a large tree of objects as shown in principle in the example above.

If I would add all possible events to the abstract base class, I would get *nice type hints* and *code completion* in PyCharm and see which events are possible for an object. But, the event system would call the existing method in the abstract base class for every object.

My question is:

**Is there a way, how I can add all possible event methods to an abstract base class to get type hints and code completion - but do not actually add functionality to the code?**

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If you define your abstract base class, you just put the abstract methods on there.

Comment: Yes, but this method would add an attribute to the class. Then, every object would have every event method defined in the abstract base class.

Comment: How else do you imagine it could work?

Comment: What you are trying to express is a `Union[ObjectA, ObjectB]`, not sure if that helps with your ultimate goal of code completion though...